# Informix server with SQLI protocol and DRDA Protocol at same time

Tags: informix

In order to make IBM Data Server client to connect to my Informix server, I need to configure it to use the DRDA protocol. 
My question is: will I be able to keep the old SQLI protocol too after configuring the DRDA protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to make sure both SQLI and DRDA protocols are configured in the ONCONFIG file and the SQLHOSTS file. You'll also need to make sure that you are using different port numbers for each of the protocol listeners.